# FastAPI: How to return a dictionary that includes numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, server, web-applications, fastapi

I get the following error when I try to access the `'data'` variable from the endpoint `'/'`.

```
ValueError: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

This is how FastAPI backend looks like:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
data = {}
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    data[1]  =  [...] ...(numpy array)
    data[2]  = [...] ...(numpy array)
    return data


@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {'Data': data}
```

When I launch the endpoint I see `'Internal Server Error'`. Nothing would display at the endpoint `'/'`. However, if I add this line -> `'print(data)'` just above the return in home function for endpoint `'/'`, it does print the values stored in the `data` dictionary, as specified in the startup function. How can I fix the issue, so that the `data` variable becomes visible when accessing the `'/'` endpoint?

Comment: where is data defined and what does it look like?

Comment: I added three more lines of code to the above code snippet.
Here,

    app = FastAPI()
    data = {}

... startup:
    ... function definition

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it seems to run fine for me, maybe there is some other part in your code that causes the problem?

Comment: Really? Could you see the results when you visit endpoint '/'? 
There is only import statements apart from the code I wrote.

Comment: Yeah. I get this `{"Data":{"1":1,"2":11}}` at the endpoint '/' . Do you have any more information in your error log?

Comment: Yes, I figured. When I change the values to be numpy arrays then, they do not work. I get internal server error.

Comment: FastAPI has no idea how it should decode numpy arrays as JSON. Return a native Python datatype or JSON yourself. Also, include the actual error message you get in your question as that makes it easier for other people to debug your problem.

Comment: Solved. Had to convert numpy array to json

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

You should convert (serialise) any numpy arrays into `JSON` before returning the data. Example:

```py
data = {}
data[1] = json.dumps(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).tolist())
data[2] = json.dumps(np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]).tolist())
return data
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, you could serialise the whole dictionary object and return it in a [custom `Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response), such as below:

```py
from fastapi import Response

json_data = json.dumps({k: v.tolist() for k, v in data.items()})
return Response(content=json_data, media_type="application/json")
```

### Option 3

Another option would be to use [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/)—which is used internally by FastAPI when returning a value, in order to convert objects that are not serializable into `str`—and then, return a [`JSONResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#jsonresponse), or a [custom `Response` directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/) (as demonstrated in the previous option), which will return an `application/json` encoded response to the client, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804).

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

json_data = jsonable_encoder({k: v.tolist() for k, v in data.items()})
return JSONResponse(content=json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI has no idea how it should decode numpy arrays to JSON; instead, do it explicitly yourself and then return the structure as native Python datatypes or as a raw JSON string. [You can do this by using the custom `Response` objects in FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response).

```
return Response(content=numpy_as_json, media_type="application/json")
```

Or if you have it formatted as native datatypes:

```
return JSONResponse(content=numpy_as_native_datatypes)
```