# How to return separate JSON responses using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, jsonresponse

I am not sure if this is part of OpenAPI standard. I am trying to develop an API server to replace an existing one, which is not open source and vendor is gone. One particular challenge I am facing is it returns multiple JSON objects **without enclosing them** either in a `list` or `array`.
For example, it returns the following 3 JSON objects as they are, in separate lines:

```
{"items": 10}
{"order": "shelf", "amount": 100}
{"id": 100, "date": "2022-01-01", "status": "X"}
```

**Not** in a `list` format `()` or in array `[]`.

For example, the code below returns all 3 objects in an array:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    data_1 = {"items": 10}
    data_2 = {"order": "shelf", "amount": 100}
    data_3 = {"id": 100, "date": "2022-01-01", "status": "X"}
    return data_1, data_2, data_3
```

Can anyone help me to get this done with FastAPI?

Comment: return JsonResponse({1:data_1, 2:data_2, 3:data_3})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

You could return a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) directly, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804), as well as  in Option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71265664/17865804).

##### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
import json

app = FastAPI()


def to_json(d):
    return json.dumps(d, default=str)
    
  
@app.get('/')
async def main():
    data_1 = {'items': 10}
    data_2 = {'order': 'shelf', 'amount': 100}
    data_3 = {'id': 100, 'date': '2022-01-01', 'status': 'X'}
    json_str = '\n'.join([to_json(data_1), to_json(data_2), to_json(data_3)])
    return Response(json_str, media_type='application/json')
```

### Option 2

You could use a [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75837557/17865804). You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) helpful. If the generator function performs some blocking operations that would block the event loop, then you could define the `gen()` function below with a normal `def` instead of `async def`, and FastAPI will use `iterate_in_threadpool()` to run the generator in a separate thread that will then be `await`ed. Have a look at the linked answers above for more details.

##### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import json

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    data_1 = {'items': 10}
    data_2 = {'order': 'shelf', 'amount': 100}
    data_3 = {'id': 100, 'date': '2022-01-01', 'status': 'X'}
    
    async def gen():
        for d in [data_1, data_2, data_3]:
            yield json.dumps(d, default=str) + '\n'

    return StreamingResponse(gen(), media_type='application/json')
```

### Option 3

As mentioned in the comments section above, one could also return a dictionary of `dict` (JSON) objects. However, using this solution, adding a line break between the objects would not be feasible.

##### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    data_1 = {'items': 10}
    data_2 = {'order': 'shelf', 'amount': 100}
    data_3 = {'id': 100, 'date': '2022-01-01', 'status': 'X'}
    return {1: data_1, 2: data_2, 3: data_3}
```

---

### Note

Although in Options 1 & 2 the `media_type` is set to `application/json`, the returned object would not be a valid JSON, as JSON strings **do not** allow real newlines (only escaped ones, i.e., `\\n`)—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72246260/17865804) as well. Hence, in Swagger UI autodocs at `/docs`, you may come across the following message when testing the endpoint: `can't parse JSON.  Raw result:`. If you would like to avoid getting that message, then you could set the `media_type` to `text/plain` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much.  "\n".join works. 100% agree this is not json format. It works with the existing client. Documentation? What is that? :-)

Comment: FastAPI provides [automatic API documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs) based on OpenAPI and Swagger UI, which people can use to test their API directly from the browser. You can find the docs at `/docs`; for instance, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs`. If you would like to disable the doucmentation in production, please have a look [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/#openapi-url), [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/#docs-urls) and [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/conditional-openapi/).