# How to make progressively loading JSON responses work with FastAPI + React

Tags: python, reactjs, streaming, fastapi, server-sent-events

I have a problem where I have a FastAPI endpoint that returns a list of JSON objects. The API might become slow at times but I want the responses to be streamable so that they're ready to be rendered by the React Frontend as soon as they are available.

I can think of two approaches.

1. Use `Server-Sent-Events`. This can work with [sse-starlette](https://github.com/sysid/sse-starlette). The problem is that there are two backend APIs involved. I have a microservice API that produces the JSON results and a backend API interfaced with the microservice that simply authenticates user requests and relays the response back. If I use SSE on the microservice API, I would have to use another SSE client at my backend to intercept and resend the SSE events.
2. Use `StreamingResponse`. This is good because I can return a StreamingResponse from the microservice and read that response line by line and stream it back from my backend. The only problem with this is that the content is in bytes and I have to parse a stream of bytes to identify individual JSON objects.

Basically, I want to yield each result object one by one and make them available for my Frontend to render progressively.

I am not opposed to either of these ideas or an even better option, if any. The point of this post is to get an idea about how this can be achieved as I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75837557/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76122475/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would check if the streaming is really needed. Why is it that the “API might become slow at times”? For example if the call from the backend to the microservice is slow, it would be better to merge them into a single server to remove the overhead.

If you really need it because generating the list is slow or the list is too large, I would suggest pagination. Basically, the React frontend will first ask and render the first part of the list, then the second, and so on. Each part is a separate API call. You could use a library like [fastapi-pagination](https://uriyyo-fastapi-pagination.netlify.app/) for that if you want.

StreamingResponse seems more complicated to me and I am not familiar with Server-Sent-Events.

*Disclaimer: I work mostly with Javascript and PHP. I did Python in the past but never made an API with it.*

Answer (score 0):

Mabye you can paste your code then we can have a better understanding.

Your auth api seems a middleware? Why dont make it before jsong generator request?

Below is the backend code:

```
import json
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse


def sse_pack(event: str, message: str):
    # Format data as an SSE message
    packet = "event: %s\n" % event
    data = {'message': message}

    packet += "data: %s\n" % json.dumps(data)
    packet += "\n"
    return packet


def get_json_streaming():
    json_stream = <yourJsonListGenerator>
    for json in json_stream:
        yield sse_pack('json',  json)
    yield sse_pack('done', {
        'jsonListId': 1,
    })


@app.post("/api/json/")
async def request_handler(params: yourModel):
    auth: bool =  get_auth_by_api()
    
    if auth == True:
        response: StreamingResponse = StreamingResponse(get_json_streaming(), media_type="text/event-stream")
        return response
```

And in the front end:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import viteLogo from "/vite.svg";
import "./App.css";
import {EventStreamContentType, fetchEventSource} from '@microsoft/fetch-event-source'

function App() {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState('');
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const abortFetch = () => {
    if (controller) {
      controller.abort()
    } 
  }

  
  const REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS = 60;

  const requestTimeoutId = setTimeout(
    () => controller.abort(),
    REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS,
  );

  let responseText = "";
  let remainText = "";
  let finished = false;

  const fetchReply = async () => {
    setMessages("");

    fetchEventSource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "yourPara": "value"
      }),
      signal: controller.signal,

      async onopen(response) {
        clearTimeout(requestTimeoutId);
        const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
        console.log(
          "success get resp",
          contentType,
        );

        if (response.ok && response.headers.get("content-type") === EventStreamContentType) {
          console.log("Connection made ", response);
          
        } else if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 500 && response.status !== 429) {
          // client-side errors are usually non-retriable:
          console.error("Fatal error, stopping retries.");
        } else {
          console.error("Encountered retriable error, but stopping retries.");
        }
      },
      onmessage(msg) {

        console.log(msg);
        if (msg.event === "FatalError") {

          console.error("Fatal error from server, stopping:", msg.data);
          abortFetch()
          // Potentially call abortFetch here if you want to cancel the fetch
        }
        const parsedObj = JSON.parse(msg["data"]);
        console.log(parsedObj.message)
        setMessages((prevMessages) => `${prevMessages}${parsedObj.message}\n`);
                // Handle other messages or events as needed
      },
      onclose() {
        console.log("Connection closed by server.");
        abortFetch()
        // You may want to handle cleanup here
      },
      onerror(err) {

        console.log("There was an error from server", err);
        abortFetch()
      },
    });
  };
  

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => fetchReply()}>
          count is {messages}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```